# Google VR SDK - Close button isn't working

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-vr

I'm using google VR SDK For Unity to play videos 360.
However, on Android, if I click in (X) button. It is crashing my application.
In the google documentation is explaining to handle escape button to listen to X button. I've implemented using following code:

```
if (GvrViewer.Instance != null) {
    GvrViewer.Instance.UpdateState (); 
    if (GvrViewer.Instance.BackButtonPressed) { 
    //Do something when (x) button is pressed
    }
}
```

When app is crashing, no logs is appearing.

Does anybody know what is needed to detect when (x) is pressed?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

> Note, the close button was briefly broken (mentioned [here](https://github.com/googlevr/gvr-unity-sdk/issues/601)) due to a
>   Unity bug (case 893219), but is now fixed ([release notes](https://unity3d.com/unity/whats-new/unity-5.6.0)).

When clicking ✕ (close) or ◀ (back), your Unity app will see an **escape** key press, which you can handle in your code by looking for the key down event:

```cs
void Update() {
  if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Escape)) {
    // Android close icon or back button tapped.
    Application.Quit();
  }
}
```

In development and testing you can inject an artificial escape press using

```bash
$ adb shell input keyevent KEYCODE_ESCAPE
```

Verified that this is working as expected in Unity 5.6.2p3 (recent QA patch release) using [GVR SDK](https://github.com/googlevr/gvr-unity-sdk) 1.70.0. Newer releases can be expected to work as well of course.